# How to get the total value of a address including tokens other than ETH

Tags: wallets, etherscan, erc

Is there a way to get the total value of a ETH address, not only its ETH value? I know Etherscan shows this on their website but I don't know if there is an API where I can grab this data, preferably through python.

[image]

For reference I can see the token value and ETH value and adding those should give the total wallet value. How can I do this using an API?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like etherscan only provides ETH balance (in eth) in their APIs.

But you could get all of the tokens of an account with ethers.js (or web3.py it doesn't really change much) [like this](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/183), get the token's name, and fetch the coingecko [apis](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation).

Another way would be checking uniswap tokenA/tokenB and then calculating the $ value, this would be way more accurate but also more complicated.

Unfortunately, there is no easy way of doing this.